# How can I allow specific strings in an edittext and show these string to the user?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, autocomplete, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` in a layout.
I want to "allow" the user to be able to enter only a string that is part of a predefined set of string I have (an array of 8 strings).
How would I show the user the only options to type that are the ones part of my list of 8 string when he presses in my EdiText?

Comment: Have you seen my answer ?

Comment: @ZygoteInit:I used `AutoCompleteTextView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should help:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html
also you may need to add a textchange listener.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to use a custom [`MaskedEditText`](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spinner instead of EditText and load it with your array

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity() , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item , yourArray);
            arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            yourSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```